# Set Navigation Title Text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionViewController and trying to set navigation title..
but none of these works...It does not show the text!

```
self.titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
self.titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Bold" size:15];
self.titleLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.titleLabel.text = [self.navigationItem title];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.titleLabel;
[self.titleLabel setText:@"title"];

self.navigationItem.title = @"The title";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the frame of your new label bigger.  The height of a nav bar is fixed at 44 pixels.

For example: CGRectMake(100,0,120,44);

The width and origins depend on what else is on the navbar, and the width of the navbar.